# Unable to create .cer

Tags: ios, xcode, keychain, cer

After I formatted my MAC and installed XCode, I wanted to generate the ipa. I navigated to `XCode -> Preferences -> Accounts -> View Details`, I did not see anything in signing identities table. When I logged in to the developer account, I am not able to upload .certSigningRequest to get a new .cer file. Below is the screenshot.

[image]

How do I create a certificate and install it in my formatted keychain? I don't have the old copy now and I am only depended on the apple developer website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Benjamin's answer helped in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10590356/xcode-the-private-key-for-is-not-installed-on-this-mac-distributing).

And I revoked my certificates that were there in my apple developer account.

Issue solved.