# How to transfer keys to a private section?

Tags: xcode, key, private, software-distribution

when I published the app to App Store I received a message. How to fix this?

Thank You!

[image]

Comment: Try solutions from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10590356/xcode-the-private-key-for-is-not-installed-on-this-mac-distributing

Comment: Also checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16563364/how-can-i-add-private-key-to-the-distribution-certificate